# String splitters for fullname into logical string with Initials

Tags: java

Hi I am looking for a function which split a long full name string into a logical string.
To make it more clear I am taking an example:

```
String Name= "Jorge Peter Wagh";
```

If I call a function like below:

```
splitedName = getSplitedName("LongSting", maxCharLength);
```

**Scenario 1:**

```
String finalName = getSplitedName("Name", 6);
```

Then the result(finalName ) should be: `Jorge`

**Scenario 2:**

```
String finalName = getSplitedName("Name", 11);// Editing, minor correction
```

Then the result(finalName) should be: `Jorge P. W.`

**Scenario 3:**

```
String finalName = getSplitedName("Name", 15); // Editing, minor correction
```

Then the result(finalName) should be: `Jorge Peter W.`

Can anyone help me. Your help will be appreciated indeed.

**EDITIED:**

In Dan's code I have added few extra  lines inside for loop to handle condition where the maxlength is less than 5:

if(i==0 && (maxCharLength < splitted[i].length()) && (maxCharLength>1)){

finalName += splitted[i].substring(0,1) + ".";
                break;

}

Thanks in advance.

Andi

Comment: What's your definition of 'logical'? Saying you want a max length of 10, but you only get 7 (first example) or 14 when you want 16 seems illogical to me.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: yeah logical means your words should not be splited into half or any incomplete word which does not make sense. Like If name is "Peter Buch" and maxLimt is 8 then it should not split like"Peter Bu". It should be "Peter B." Though the actual lengh it getting reduced but thats the way it should be.

Comment: Heads-up: people are very likely to downvote or even close your question, since it amounts to "gimme teh codez".   This site likes it when you've tried by yourself and are having issues.

Comment: Why would you ever want to display `Jorge Peter W.` instead of `Jorge P. Wagh`?

Comment: @user2172581: This statement is still not completely unambiguous: "words should not be splited into half or any incomplete word which does not make sense".  Words like "logical" and "make sense" are not useful when defining a technical system, because they cannot be translated into a set of clear, unambiguous rules.

Comment: Why doesn't the last one return the full string?

Comment: supersam654, you are right, I have made the correction, thanx for correcting me

Comment: What happens if you pass it length 8? And length 4? On a side note, generally describing *exactly* what happens (not just with examples) is a necessary step in programming and it should also help you a lot with writing the code (once you have some programming experience, it should almost naturally lead to the code for simple problems).

Comment: Hi Dukeling, if length 8 then the result should be "Peter J." and if length is 4 then the result should be "P." however this would not be the case in real life scenario. By the way thanks a lot for your knowledge sharing with me. I am new to the programming thus will learn things gradually.

Answer (score 0):

I don't normally do people's homework for them, but I was bored.

```
String getSplitedName(String s, int len)
{
  if (len >= s.length())
    return s;
  String s2 = s.substring(0, len + 1);
  int index = s2.lastIndexOf(" ");
  if (index == -1)
    return "";
  if (index < s2.length() - 3)
    return s2.substring(0, index + 2) + ".";
  return s2.substring(0, index);
}
```

For:

```
String name = "Jorge Peter Wagh";
System.out.println(getSplitedName(name, 6));
System.out.println(getSplitedName(name, 10));
System.out.println(getSplitedName(name, 12));
System.out.println(getSplitedName(name, 15));
System.out.println(getSplitedName(name, 16));
```

Prints:

```
Jorge
Jorge P.
Jorge Peter
Jorge Peter W.
Jorge Peter Wagh
```

Comment: thnx Dukeling... however I have made little changes in my scenario as per the comments by supersam654